# How to make Facebook for iPhone open links in Safari?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, facebook, google

Is there a way to make Facebook for iPhone (and other iPhone apps like Google & Yelp) always open links in Safari (or YouTube, etc.) instead of in an internal web view?

The native apps like Safari & Youtube seem to usually work much better than web views. Plus, iOS 9 adds a back button that takes you back to the original app with one tap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such possibility. App developer would need to implement this in the app.

P.S. You can open links from Facebook in Safari -> click "Share" when viewing the link and choose "Open in Safari".

[image]

<sup>Image from: [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/201229/make-facebook-on-android-open-links-in-the-default-browser/)</sup>

Comment: OK. Thanks. I know that, but I want links to open in Safari on the first tap.